# How do I get the price from AdMob in Unity AIP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to pull in the price for In App Purchases (IAP) using Unity Ads and  AdMob.

```
public void InitializePurchasing()
{
    // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
    if (IsInitialized())
    {
        // ... we are done here.
        return;
    }
    var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

    builder.AddProduct(PRODUCT_REMOVE_ADS, ProductType.NonConsumable);

    UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);

    removeAdsPriceText.text = m_StoreController.products.WithID("removeads").metadata.localizedPrice.ToString(); // This should be the code to get the price
}
```

Price in the Editor when I hit play:
[image]

This is the price when I build the app to Google Play and run the app.
[image]

It is suppose to be $1.99.
[image]

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Here is what I have so far.  When I press play in the inspector the price goes to $0.01, but when I build it to my phone it doesn't change. removeAdsText.text=m_StoreController.products.WithID("removeads").metadata.localizedPrice.ToString();

Comment: Are the goal to make an IAP that removes ads?

Comment: I have two IAPs one removes ads and the other unlocks everything.

Comment: You said you needed the price of the item? https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-get-item-price.391448/

Comment: If you only get the price in the inspector, you might have to print it in some graphical user interface :P

Comment: I have the price printing to a graphical interface, it just isn't pulling the price when I make a live build.

Comment: I recommend you file for a bug [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues) and let them know what your problem is.

Comment: Issue has been added to that bug list

Comment: Have You cross checked currency codes, may it be printed as australian dollars (or similar) instead of usd?

Comment: Currently, it is just showing the numbers I put in there, not the local price, I live in the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution

The code needs to be called `OnInitialized`

```
public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
{
    m_StoreController = controller;
    m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;

    removeAdsPriceText.text = m_StoreController.products.WithID("removeads").metadata.localizedPriceString;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help!